# jaydebeapi for both Netezza and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, netezza, jaydebeapi

I am using jaydebeapi in python 3 to run queries. 
I need to connect to Netezza and MySql both. my code runs both queries separately without any problem but when I run one after another it gives an error for the second one.
I close both connection and cursor for the first query (Netezza) but still get the following error:

```
jpype._jexception.RuntimeExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't that you need to close one connection in order to use the other. The issue is that, when `jaydebeapi` is using `jpype` for communication, you only get one opportunity to provide all of the necessary JAR file paths you may use. This can be seen in the `_jdbc_connect_jpype` function, [here](https://github.com/baztian/jaydebeapi/blob/master/jaydebeapi/__init__.py#L160-L176).

The fix is to pass *all* JAR file paths you may use during execution of your program.

> I'm assuming you aren't running on Jython and instead `jaydebeapi`
>   automatically installed `jpype` to facilitate Python to Java
>   communication. This is the most likely scenario for an "out of the
>   box" situation. If you are using Jython, let me know.

Comment: Is there any way around it? I need to switch between Netezza and Mysql frequently

Comment: When calling the connect function just pass in both JAR paths. That should fix it.

Comment: If you'd like, share your `connect` statement for both Netezza and MySQL and I can show you the code you should use instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yu need add Class Mysql Driver and JAR file path, example to DB2 with IMB jar:

conn = jaydebeapi.connect("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver",
                           "url",
                           ["user", "password"],
                           "C:\lib\jt400.jar",)